# Proof that the stochastic integral is a gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, brownian-motion

Let B a Brownian motion. I want to show that What I want to show is that $$\int_0^tf(s)\,dB_s$$ is a gaussian process, where f(t) is a deterministic and continuous function.
From the definition of stochastic process we know: $$ \sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}f(s)(B_{t_{i}^n}-B_{t_{i-1}^n}) \to \int_0^tf(s)\,dB_s=X_t$$
I can observe that $\sum_{i=1}^{K_n-1}f(s)(B_{t_{i}^n}-B_{t_{i-1}^n})$ is a sum of independent normal random variable and therefore is still Normal. Moreover also the limit of normal r.v. is still normal. I can then conclude that $\int_0^tf(s)\,dB_s$ is a Normal random variable.

Now is coming the part where I have some doubt:
Can i conclude that vec$(X_{t_1},.. X_{t_n})$  is multivariate normal saying that each $X_{t_1},.. X_{t_n}$ is an independent normal random variable? I'm not sure about the independence. It seems to me that they are independent since every $X_{t_1}$ is the result of a sum of independent random variable.

Any help please?

Comment: The increments $X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}$ are independent but the random variables $X_{t_i}$ are not independent (just consider $f=1$ constant).

Comment: How could I show that $X_{t_i}-X_{t{_i-1}}$ are independent? once done that, i could say that vec$(X_{t_1},.. X_{t_n})$ is multivariate normal since each component could be represented as $\sum_{i=1}^jX_{t_i}-X_{t{_i-1}}$ and $j=1,..,n$. But also in this case, there is not the same problem as before? i would conclude that vec$(X_{t_1},.. X_{t_n})$ is multivariate normal since each component is normal and independent (found summing the independent increment). (this is the proof that i also see showing that an independent increment process with gaussian increments is a gaussian process)